# Is there a way to change default capabilities in mods (or anithing else) without changing the access.php file in moodle?

Tags: moodle

On my moodle install I want to set that the users can't add new entries to any glossary activity by default.

- I now i can do it through modifying the capabilities manually in each activity through Glossary Administration -> Permissions but I want to set it to all instances by default.
- I know i can also do it globally by modifying the access.php file in /mod/glossary/db/ but it is not the best option if I want to upgrade later.

So my question is, is there some place in the admin menu where i can set these globally in the admin menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes via the roles. Go to

site admin -> users -> permissions -> define roles

Choose "Authenticated user" - this is the default role for everyone.

Click the advanced button

Then filter for "mod/glossary:write"

And change the permission to Prevent or Prohibit

- Prevent means the default user hasn't got access but it can be overruled by another role
- Prohibit means it can't be overruled by another role - only admins will have access.